# QT & C++ : Passing 'const QString' discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, qt, constants

I wrote a loop that ran fine in STL, however I've been attempting it with the proper QTL data types and it gave me the error:

```
error: passing 'const QString' as 'this' argument of 'QString& QString::operator=(char)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
      dic.at(i) = char(i);
```

The full code that I am trying to run is this:

```
    QVector <QString> dic ( 256 );
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
     dic.at(i) = char(i);
}
```

Not quite sure what I need to update in my code, any thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`QVector::at` is `const`. You want to use `dic[i]`.

Details: Because Qt's containers are copy-on-write, non-const accessors are intrinsically more expensive since they have to first check if they need to copy the underlying data (and copy it if necessary). For that reason, in Qt, `at(i)` will be faster than `operator[]`. Sadly, this is the opposite of the STL, for which, e.g., `std::vector<T>::at(i)` does bounds checking and for that reason is slightly more expensive than `std::vector<T>::operator[](i)`.