# Problem when attempting to change the value of a two-dimensional vector

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

I am trying to change the values of a two-dimensional QVector (`QVector<QVector<QString>`). However when attempting it, I get the following error: `passing 'const QString' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`.

I first thought that the problem was in the way I was accessing the data in the `QVector`. I therefore tried accessing it via `operator []`. This gave me the following error: `no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'QVector<QString>' and 'QString')`. I also tried dereferencing the vector (`*SecondList`), as I wasn't sure whether `operator []` did it and got the following error: `no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'const QVector<QString>')` .

Here is the problematic code:

```
void Handler::changePassword(QString newPassword, int id)
{
    
    QString nP = newPassword;

    int i = 0;
    bool loopBreaker = false;

    while (!loopBreaker)    
    {
        if (SecondList->at(i).at(2) == QString::number(id))
        {//Changes the value for password in "secondlist"
            SecondList->at(i).at(0) = nP;    // ----> ERROR
            loopBreaker = true;
            saveList();
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Here is the header file for `Handler`  class

```
class Handler : public QWidget
{
private: 
    QVector<QVector<QString>> *SecondList = new QVector<QVector<QString>>;
}
```

(code is ommitted for readability)

Comment: Do you really need to dynamically allocate your `QVector`? I would change `QVector<QVector<QString>> *SecondList = new QVector<QVector<QString>>;` to `QVector<QVector<QString>> SecondList;`

Comment: Yes it would be preferable. I will test without it being dynamically allocated and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: ***Yes it would be preferable*** remember that the elements of the vector are still dynamically allocated if you use `QVector<QVector<QString>> SecondList;`

Comment: I'm testing it right now, be back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QVector at()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#at) returns a **const** T&, try using [operator []](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#operator-5b-5d) instead, which returns **non-const** &

Comment: I tried `*SecondList[i][2] = nP;`, yet I get this error: `no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'QVector<QString>')`. As @drescherjm suggested it might be because of my vector being a pointer, but not the inside one.

Comment: try without leading *, i.e. just do SecondList[i][2] = nP . The * is dereferencing operator.

Comment: @WKstraw You would have to do `(*SecondList)[i][2]`.

Comment: that's what I first thought but then I got this error:  `no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'QVector<QString>' and 'QString')`

Comment: @David That's not correct. You need two indexing operations already for the two nested vectors. It would technically work to do `SecondList[0][i][2]` (because `x[y]` is literally `*(x+y)` for raw pointers) but please don't do that.

Comment: ah yeah, as Max said above do (*SecondList)[i][2] or don't do dynamic allocation

Comment: @MaxLanghof Wow, that worked, I had completely forgotten about the brackets.. Thanks!

Comment: @MaxLanghof if you want to answer I can mark it as answered (or I can do it myself, if it bothers you)

Comment: This would be a minor edit/addition to this already correct answer, I don't think adding it separately helps. Maybe @David wants to add some code to show the correct usage :)

Answer (score 0):

So Ben answered this question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24377779/11731556)

But the reason is that the `QVector::at` method is `const` and the full prototype is `const T &QVector::at(int i) const`.

So you are going to have to use the `QVector::operator[]` which the full prototype is `T &QVector::operator[](int i)`

So I would try `SecondList->operator[](i).operator[](0)  = nP;`. Something along these lines.

Comment: But why would you call `operator[]` manually instead of just using `[i]` as it was intended?

Comment: This was partly the problem, but `*SecondList[i][2] = nP;` also didn't work. As @MaxLanghof pointed out, I had just forgotten the brackets around the `*SecondList`